# C++ - Raytracer from scratch Polygon is disassembled

Tags: c++, stl, polygon, raytracing

I am trying to program a RayTracer from Scratch and want to load an .stl file into the program.
When I try to rotate the object in blender and reload it into my program it's getting disassembled.

[image]

Sadly I cannot wrap my head around it, because a single triangle gets rendered correctly as far as I can tell.
Therefore I would like to share my code and if anyone is familiar to this problem, I would be very thankful for any help!

https://code.fbi.h-da.de/stmngoeb/raytracersample/-/tree/Implement-raytracing-a-sphere

(In general a polygon gets loaded by its stl file, the vertices are parsed into a Triangle class which get rendered)

EDIT:
After requests, here are the most relevant code-parts.
First of all, the cube was created in Blender, exported as .stl with Z -> front and Y -> Up

**main.cpp**

```
Material objMaterial(Color(1,1, 0),0,0,0); // Custom material class with color, shininess, transparency and reflection
auto* polygon = new Polygon(OBJECT_PATH, objMaterial); // Custom class, will be shown below
for(auto* triangle : polygon->getTriangles()){ 
    objects.push_back(triangle); // vector of Objects(Triangle<Object)
}

auto* image = new Image(screen, 100); // Get an Image with black pixels defined by the Cameras position and the "Screen" see below
image->render(cam, objects, lightSources);
image->printToBitmap("scene.bmp");
```

**Polygon.cpp**

```
Polygon::Polygon(const std::string& path, Material material){
    load(path, material); // loads the coordinates and normals as seen below
}
```

...

```
Triangle* Polygon::getTriangleAt(Vector3 point) {
    Ray originToPoint(Vector3(0), point);
    for(auto triangle : mTriangles){
        if(triangle->isIntersectedBy(originToPoint)){
            try{
                if(point.equals(triangle->getPointOfIntersection(originToPoint))){
                    return triangle;
                }
            }catch (std::logic_error error){
                continue;
            }
        }
    }
}

Vector3 Polygon::getNormalAt(Vector3 point) {
    Triangle* triangle = getTriangleAt(point);
    return triangle->getNormalAt(point).normalize();
}

bool Polygon::isIntersectedBy(Ray cameraRay) {
    for(auto triangle : mTriangles){
        if(triangle->isIntersectedBy(cameraRay)){
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

Vector3 Polygon::getPointOfIntersection(Ray cameraRay) {
    std::vector<Vector3> intersected{};
    for(auto triangle : mTriangles){
        if(triangle->isIntersectedBy(cameraRay)){
            try{
                intersected.push_back(triangle->getPointOfIntersection(cameraRay));
            }catch (std::logic_error error){
                continue;
            }
        }
    }
    int index = getClosestCamDistance(intersected, cameraRay);
    return intersected.at(index);
}

int Polygon::getClosestCamDistance(std::vector<Vector3> points, Ray cameraRay) {
    double shortest = DBL_MAX;
    double distance = 0;
    int index = 0;
    Vector3 cameraPosition = cameraRay.getOrigin();

    for (int i=0; i<points.size(); i++){
        distance = cameraPosition.add(points.at(i).negate()).magnitude();
        if(distance<shortest){
            shortest=distance;
            index=i;
        }
    }

    return index;
}
```

**Triangle.cpp**

```
Vector3 Triangle::getPointOfIntersection(Ray cameraRay) {
    Vector3 rayDirection = cameraRay.getDirection();
    float normalDotRayDirection = mNormal.dot(rayDirection);
    float d = mNormal.dot(mA);

    double t = -(mNormal.dot(cameraRay.getOrigin())+d) / normalDotRayDirection;

    if(t<ACCURACY){
        throw std::logic_error("Point behind camera");
    }

    Vector3 intersection = cameraRay.getOrigin().add(rayDirection.mult(t));

    // edge 0
    Vector3 edge0 = mB.add(mA.negate());
    Vector3 vp0 = intersection.add(mA.negate());
    Vector3 C = edge0.cross(vp0);
    bool condition1 = (mNormal.dot(C) >= 0);

    // edge 1
    Vector3 edge1 = mC.add(mB.negate());
    Vector3 vp1 = intersection.add(mB.negate());
    C = edge1.cross(vp1);
    bool condition2 = (mNormal.dot(C) >= 0);

    // edge 2
    Vector3 edge2 = mA.add(mC.negate());
    Vector3 vp2 = intersection.add(mC.negate());
    C = edge2.cross(vp2);
    bool condition3 = (mNormal.dot(C) >= 0);

    if(condition1 && condition2 && condition3){
        return intersection;
    }else{
        throw std::logic_error("Point not in triangle");
    }
}

bool Triangle::isIntersectedBy(Ray cameraRay) {
    Vector3 rayDirection = cameraRay.getDirection();
    double a = rayDirection.dot(mNormal);

    return (a != 0);
}
```

**Image.cpp**

```
    void Image::render(Camera *camera, std::vector<Object*> objects, const std::vector<LightSource*>& lightSource) {
        std::vector<double> vertical = linspace(mScreen->getCoordinateAt(1),mScreen->getCoordinateAt(3), mScreen->getHeight());
        std::vector<double> horizontal = linspace(mScreen->getCoordinateAt(0),mScreen->getCoordinateAt(2), mScreen->getWidth());
    
        if(vertical.size()*horizontal.size() == mScreen->getPixelAmount()){
    
            int count = 0;
    
            for(double y : vertical){
                for (double x : horizontal){
                    Vector3 pixel(x,y,4);
                    Vector3 cameraRayDirection = pixel.add(camera->getPosition().negate()).normalize();
    
                    Ray cameraRay(camera->getPosition(), cameraRayDirection);
    
                    int index = getClosestIntersectedObjectByIndex(objects, cameraRay);
                    if(index != -1){
                        try{
                            Vector3 pointOfIntersection = objects.at(index)->getPointOfIntersection(cameraRay);
                            Pixel finalColor = Screen::getFinalColor(cameraRay, objects, index, lightSource, pointOfIntersection);
                            mScreen->setPixel(count, finalColor);
                        } catch (std::logic_error error) {
                            
                        }
    
                    }
                    count++;
                }
            }
        }
    }
int Image::getClosestIntersectedObjectByIndex(const std::vector<Object*>& objects, Ray cameraRay) {
    Vector3 cam = cameraRay.getOrigin();
    int size = objects.size();
    auto smallest = DBL_MAX;
    int index = -1;
    for (int i = 0; i<size; i++){
        if(objects.at(i)->isIntersectedBy(cameraRay)){
            try{
                Vector3 pointOfIntersection = objects.at(i)->getPointOfIntersection(cameraRay);
                double length = pointOfIntersection.add(cam.negate()).magnitude();
                if(length < smallest){
                    smallest = length;
                    index = i;
                }
            } catch (std::logic_error error) {

            }

        }
    }

    return index;
}
```

**Screen.cpp**

```
Pixel Screen::getFinalColor(Ray cameraRay, std::vector<Object*> objects, int index, const std::vector<LightSource*>& lightSources, Vector3 point) {
Color objectColor = objects.at(index)->getColor();
Color ambientLightAmplifier(0);
Color diffuseLightAmplifier(0);
Color specularLightAmplifier(0);

for (auto light : lightSources){
        ambientLightAmplifier = ambientLightAmplifier.add(light->getAmbientLight());
        Ray lightRay(point, light->getPosition().add(point.negate()));

        if(!objectIsShadowed(lightRay, objects)){
            diffuseLightAmplifier = diffuseLightAmplifier.add(light->getDiffuseLightAt(objects.at(index), point));
            specularLightAmplifier = specularLightAmplifier.add(light->getSpecularLightAt(cameraRay, objects.at(index), point));
        }
}

// Phong components
Color termAmbient = objectColor.mult(ambientLightAmplifier);
Color termDiffuse = objectColor.mult(diffuseLightAmplifier);
Color termSpecular = Color(1).mult(specularLightAmplifier);

Color finalColor = termAmbient.add(termDiffuse).add(termSpecular).clip();

Pixel finalPixel{
        finalPixel.r = finalColor.getRed(),
        finalPixel.g = finalColor.getGreen(),
        finalPixel.b = finalColor.getBlue()
};

return finalPixel;
}
```

**Console Output While Loading**

> coordinates of triangle 0: (-0.615123, 0.555998, -2.25002)
> (0.134102, 0.227131, -1.67512) (0.776466, 0.376492, -2.42682)
>
> normal of triangle 0: (0.161343, 0.93249, 0.323157) coordinates of
> triangle 1: (-0.615123, 0.555998, -2.25002) (0.776466, 0.376492,
> -2.42682) (0.0272415, 0.705359, -3.00172)
>
> normal of triangle 1: (0.161343, 0.93249, 0.323157) coordinates of
> triangle 2: (-0.134102, -0.227131, -3.32488) (0.0272415, 0.705359,
> -3.00172) (0.776466, 0.376492, -2.42682)
>
> normal of triangle 2: (0.642364, 0.149361, -0.751705) coordinates of
> triangle 3: (-0.134102, -0.227131, -3.32488) (0.776466, 0.376492,
> -2.42682) (0.615123, -0.555998, -2.74998)
>
> normal of triangle 3: (0.642364, 0.149361, -0.751705) coordinates of
> triangle 4: (0.615123, -0.555998, -2.74998) (0.776466, 0.376492,
> -2.42682) (0.134102, 0.227131, -1.67512)
>
> normal of triangle 4: (0.749224, -0.328867, 0.5749) coordinates of
> triangle 5: (0.615123, -0.555998, -2.74998) (0.134102, 0.227131,
> -1.67512) (-0.0272415, -0.705359, -1.99828)
>
> normal of triangle 5: (0.749224, -0.328867, 0.5749) coordinates of
> triangle 6: (-0.0272415, -0.705359, -1.99828) (-0.776466, -0.376492,
> -2.57318) (-0.134102, -0.227131, -3.32488)
>
> normal of triangle 6: (-0.161343, -0.93249, -0.323157) coordinates of
> triangle 7: (-0.0272415, -0.705359, -1.99828) (-0.134102, -0.227131,
> -3.32488) (0.615123, -0.555998, -2.74998)
>
> normal of triangle 7: (-0.161343, -0.93249, -0.323157) coordinates of
> triangle 8: (-0.776466, -0.376492, -2.57318) (-0.615123, 0.555998,
> -2.25002) (0.0272415, 0.705359, -3.00172)
>
> normal of triangle 8: (-0.749224, 0.328867, -0.5749) coordinates of
> triangle 9: (-0.776466, -0.376492, -2.57318) (0.0272415, 0.705359,
> -3.00172) (-0.134102, -0.227131, -3.32488)
>
> normal of triangle 9: (-0.749224, 0.328867, -0.5749) coordinates of
> triangle 10: (-0.0272415, -0.705359, -1.99828) (0.134102, 0.227131,
> -1.67512) (-0.615123, 0.555998, -2.25002)
>
> normal of triangle 10: (-0.642364, -0.149361, 0.751705) coordinates of
> triangle 11: (-0.0272415, -0.705359, -1.99828) (-0.615123, 0.555998,
> -2.25002) (-0.776466, -0.376492, -2.57318)
>
> normal of triangle 11: (-0.642364, -0.149361, 0.751704)
>
> Process finished with exit code 0

EDIT 08.02.2021

So in general I came to the conclusion that transforming the location in Blender causes this error. Sadly I don't know how to fix this. If the Object stays in center in Blender everything gets rendered fine.

Okay, after more debugging, the following code for checking whether the point of intersection is inside the triangle fails(condition1 is wrong).
Anyone an idea why?

```
// edge 0
Vector3 edge0 = mB.add(mA.negate());
Vector3 vp0 = intersection.add(mA.negate());
Vector3 C = edge0.cross(vp0);
bool condition1 = (mNormal.dot(C) >= 0);

// edge 1
Vector3 edge1 = mC.add(mB.negate());
Vector3 vp1 = intersection.add(mB.negate());
C = edge1.cross(vp1);
bool condition2 = (mNormal.dot(C) >= 0);

// edge 2
Vector3 edge2 = mA.add(mC.negate());
Vector3 vp2 = intersection.add(mC.negate());
C = edge2.cross(vp2);
bool condition3 = (mNormal.dot(C) >= 0);

if(condition1 && condition2 && condition3){
    return intersection; }
```

Comment: Please edit your question to include the most relevant code to your problem. Not everyone can follow that link nor do people wanting to help always have the patience to. You can wrap code in between three backticks ( ` ) at the start and end.
```print("Hello World)```

Comment: That's a university restricted gitlab isnt it? Cant access that link

Comment: It's just a guess, but I think you are applying transformations (rotation and translation) in a different order.

Comment: Sorry for the inconvenience, I added the necessary code to the question^^